# Displays a list of portfolios without an image in the avada theme fusion wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to display the portfolio list (only the title) without thumbnails on Avada theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your portfolio items are created as custom post type you can create a custom wordpress query to get them.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type_slug',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$portfolio_items = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $portfolio_items->have_posts() ){
    while( $portfolio_items->have_posts() ){
        $portfolio_items->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can hide all images using CSS `display: none;`.